# Python ругается, когда я пытаюсь в input тексте для пользователя добавить переменную i

Tags: python, input

Всем доброго времени суток! Я хочу, чтобы для пользователя был сменяющийся текст, в зависимости от номера элемента, который ему нужно сейчас ввести:

```
kol = int(input("Введите количество элементов: "))
lis = []
for i in range(kol):
    k = (input("Введите элемент № ", i))
    lis.append(k)
print(lis)
```

```
Дебаггер выдает:
    k = (input("Введите элемент № ", i))
         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
TypeError: input expected at most 1 argument, got 2
```

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как правильно синтаксически записать данное выражение, чтобы было как в print, но Питон не воспринимал его, как 2 аргумента?
Спасибо!

Comment: Используйте f-строку `k = input(f"Введите элемент № {i}")`

Comment: Или просто плюсик поставьте вместо запятой: `k = (input("Введите элемент № " + i))`

Comment: @Глеб плюсика мало, нужно тогда еще str()

Comment: А, ну да. Просто новичку f-строки могут показаться сложными.

Comment: Спасибо! f-строка помогла!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Есть два варианта, как исправить Вашу ошибку:

1. Использовать символ **`+`** для конкатенации строк:

   `k = input("Введите элемент № " + str(i) + ": ")`
2. Форматирование с помощью f-строк (в фигурных скобках указывайте переменные):

   `k = input(f"Введите элемент № {i}: ")`

Вы также можете сократить код до трёх строк с помощью генератора списка:

```
kol = int(input("Введите количество элементов: "))
lis = [input(f"Введите элемент №{i}: ") for i in range(kol)]

print(lis)
```